How to specify Microsoft.NetCore.App version in VS2022
I create an asp.net core app, using .net 8. It works normally. But today, when I start Debug, the console say:
You must install or update .NET to run this application.
App: /var/www/MinAPI/WebApi.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '8.0.11' (x64)

Last week, i have to installed .net sdk 8.0.10 because the same reason.
I added global.json, like this:
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "8.0.10"
  }
}

I also added runtimeconfig.template.json:
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net8.0",
    "rollForward": "Minor",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "8.0.10"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "8.0.10"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Globalization.Invariant": false,
      "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.IsSupported": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}

But no effect.
I uninstall Microsoft ASP.NET Core 8.0.11 - Shared Framework and project works normally.
So, how to specify version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App to avoid this?

If you're placing the options in the template JSON file, omit the runtimeOptions property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/#example-runtimeconfigtemplatejson-file

I also added runtimeconfig.template.json--youdon't have to add it yourself,it would be in \bin\Debug\net8.0 folder
